# Rudin rapidity with the sum of inverse factorial

Tags: real-analysis

While I'm going through theorem 3.31 in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, I'm confused about a step here. [image: picture]. I could not figure out how Rudin comes up with the formula after e - $s_n$. Could anyone give me a hint? (It is known that $e$ = $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to realize that $
\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{x^k}{k!} = e^x
$. So, in particular, you have that $e = \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{1}{k!}$. Hence,
$$
e -s_n = \sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{1}{k!} - \sum_{k \leq n} \frac {1}{k!} = \sum_{k \ge n+1}\frac{1}{k!}.
$$

Comment: I found myself stuck on the reason why $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}${1+$\frac{1}{n+1}$+$\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$+...} = $\frac{1}{n!n}$ too... Could you please offer some guidance on this too?

Comment: @col that is the geometric series formula.

Comment: @SuzuHirose that makes sense! thx y'all